# Why am I getting an AttributeError when trying to traverse a linked list?

Tags: python, linked-list

I am trying to write a search() function to search a linked list for a node with the requested value and return the node.

Below is my code:

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value
        self.next = None

class LinkedList:
    def __init__(self):
        self.head = None

    def to_list(self):
        out = []
        node = self.head
        while node:
            out.append(node.value)
            node = node.next
        return out

    def search(self, value):
        """ Search the linked list for a node with the requested value  and return the node. """
        # Traverse through the list until a number is found
        node = self.head
        print(node)
        while node != value:
            node = node.next
        return node

# Test search
linked_list = LinkedList()
linked_list.prepend(2) # Method not shown for brevity
linked_list.prepend(1)
linked_list.append(4) # Method not shown for brevity
linked_list.append(3)
linked_list.to_list()
assert linked_list.search(1).value == 1, f"list contents: {linked_list.to_list()}"
assert linked_list.search(4).value == 4, f"list contents: {linked_list.to_list()}"
```

Running this code gives me the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-58-d70897699f08> in <module>()
      6 linked_list.append(3)
      7 linked_list.to_list()
----> 8 assert linked_list.search(1).value == 1, f"list contents: {linked_list.to_list()}"
      9 assert linked_list.search(4).value == 4, f"list contents: {linked_list.to_list()}"

<ipython-input-54-c7f29bb4a2be> in search(self, value)
      5     print(node)
      6     while node != value:
----> 7         node = node.next
      8     return node
      9 

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'next'
```

Can anyone point out why I am getting this AttributeError? Had used very similar traversal code in the to_list method so am not sure why I"m encountering this issue in the search method.

Comment: seems like you may be at the end? Where `node.next` becomes none, so you try to access `None.next` which is not possible?

Comment: Tip: represent an empty list with `self.head = Node(0)` rather than `self.head = None`. Now all other methods can assume that `self.head.next` refers to the head (if any) of the list, rather than having to cater to `self.head` being a `Node` or `None`. The dummy node can be used to store metadata (such as the length) about the list.

Answer (score 1):

The text `while node != value` is plain wrong. The `node` variable should contain `Node` objects or `None`. As no node object can be the *integer* 1 (even if its *value* attribute could), you end with `None` and raise the error.

What you want is:

```
while node and (node.value != value):
    ...
```